# Looping through Facebook\GraphObject Object in php - how is it done?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, object

I've tried a bunch of different ways from Google and Stack, and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphObject/4.0.0?locale=en_GB, but I can't successfully loop through this object. I want to test if the email permission is granted or declined. How is looping done with this? Thanks for your guidance.

```
Facebook\GraphObject Object
(
    [backingData:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [permission] => public_profile
                    [status] => granted
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [permission] => email
                    [status] => declined
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the asArray() method of GraphObject

```
foreach($graphObject->asArray() as $data) {
    // data is a stdClass
    $status = $data->status;
}
```